# I cant find the memory leak in this function (SDL/OpenGL)

Tags: c++, opengl, memory, memory-leaks, sdl

So this function:

```
Texture::Texture(std::string text,TTF_Font * font,int w,int h,int ox,int oy,Uint8 r,Uint8 g,Uint8 b,bool middle)
{
    SDL_Color textColor = {r,g,b};
    SDL_Surface * textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,text.c_str(),textColor);
    textSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface(textSurface,sample->format,0);
    float surfAspectRatio = textSurface->w / textSurface->h;
    float texAspectRatio = w / h;
    if(texAspectRatio > surfAspectRatio)//space is to wide so orient to hieight
    {
        if(middle)
        {
            texCoords = new HitBox(-h * surfAspectRatio / 2,-h / 2,h * surfAspectRatio,h,ox,oy,0);
        }
        else
        {
            texCoords = new HitBox(-.1,-.1,h * surfAspectRatio,h,ox,oy,0);
        }
    }
    else//to tall
    {
        if(middle)
        {
            texCoords = new HitBox(-w / 2,-w * (1 / surfAspectRatio) / 2,w,w * (1 / surfAspectRatio),ox,oy,0);
        }
        else
        {
            texCoords = new HitBox(-.1,-.1,w,w * (1 / surfAspectRatio),ox,oy,0);
        }
    }
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    texData = NULL;
    texData = new Picture();
    glGenTextures(1,&texData->texID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,texData->texID);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, textSurface->w,
                 textSurface->h, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
                 textSurface->pixels);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,NULL);
    SDL_FreeSurface(textSurface);
    texData->fileName = "text";
}
```

Takes a string and uses `SDL_ttf` to render text. Then the `if else` stuff in the middle does some math to find the location and size the new texture should be. I don't that the problem is here.Then the last part converts the SDL_Surface to an open GL texture.

Here is what the texture class looks like.

```
class Texture
{
public:
    Picture * texData;
    HitBox * texCoords;
    Texture(int,int,int,int,int,std::string,int,int);
    Texture(std::string,TTF_Font *,int,int,int,int,Uint8,Uint8,Uint8,bool);
    Texture(const Texture *);
    ~Texture();
    void render_tex();
};
```

I know that the memory leak is in this function and doesn't have any thing to do with a problem in the destructor because there is no memory leak when I use the other constructor.

The memory leak is about 3kb I think although that is a very rough estimate.

Comment: @DOUGLAS O. MOEN yes there is a Destructor for `Picture` and `Hitbox` does not need one because it contains no pointers. There is one for Texture as well but I am pretty sure that is not the problem because when I use the other constructor there is no problem so that would indicate that The problem is here.

Comment: @DOUGLAS O. MOEN I know the destructor works because when I use the other constructor there is no memory leak. Additionally `st4lk3r87`solved the problem for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SDL_Surface * textSurface = TTF_RenderText_Solid(font,text.c_str(),textColor);
textSurface = SDL_ConvertSurface(textSurface,sample->format,0);
```

I guess the leak is properly on the second line copied above.

From the documentation SDL_ConvertSurface create a NEW surface from the one passed. So you are leaking the SDL_Surface created with TTF_RenderTextSolid function cause you use the same pointer to store the first and the second surface.